# Connect two networks across another router

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I'm trying to get a network setup with three routers, and three DHCP servers. Sounds silly, but if I can get it to work, I can eliminate a lot of re-wiring, etc in the building.

I have a modem/router A with an active DHCP server ip 10.1.10.1
I have a router B with ip address 10.1.10.10 and a dhcp server distributing 192.168.0.100-250
I have a router C with ip address 10.1.10.11 and a dhcp server distributing 192.168.1.100-250
(So B is connected to A, and C is connected to A)

I don't mind having the networks on Router B and C separate (C is in the office, so it's actually kind of nice being on a different network) but the printer is on B, and it would be nice to be able to print to it from a device on A. Basically, I want the 192.168.0.1 router to communicate with the 192.168.1.1 router.

The only reason I haven't set them both up as access points is because on B, I have a Raspberry Pi on a TV which needs a reserved address to be able to use the XBMC remote for it, which Modem/Router A cannot do.

Both B and C need to be connected to A (for internet), and wiring B to C is not possible (they're on two opposite sides of a building with no clear way to wire it without ripping up walls).

I've been playing with static routes, but I'm failing miserably. Is that even the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one. Because you use individual address ranges behind routers, each zone becomes a private network where all internal devices are only visible to eachother.

A printer in group B will therefor only be visible and approachable to other devices in group B.

In your situation I would make Router A be the main router for the entire network, issuing DHCP for all devices, and configure Router B and Router C to be bridges/routers. If you have a spare lan port on the routers and you don't want to have any configure issues, just move the cable from the WAN to one of the LAN ports on routers B and C.

As a result, all devices will see eachother in all 3 groups. You can still leave group C unchanged to shield it off the rest, but those people will not be able to print to the printer.